# Merge two tables in ascending order in R

Tags: r

It is the first time I am asking a question on Stack, but I use it a lot since I began to code to years ago. It always helped me a lot.

I have two tables with many columns that define some conditions (exact same number of columns on the two tables), the main ones being 'Company' and 'Price'. My main idea was to merge them so I can have each characteristic from each company in columns and see wether they match with mine or not. As they won't have all the time the exact same price, my idea was to use a new column with the price rounded so there will be a match to merge them.

I used join or merge function in R based on the rounded price column (you will see below). But when I merge it, no matter with which function, it disorders the rows and the nearest price points are not aligned in the columns, so I can't compare them...

```
 Company.ZZ Price.ZZ Price_round Company.XZ Price.XZ
 1          ZZ       80         100         XZ       82
 2          ZZ       80         100         XZ       93
 3          ZZ      175         200         XZ      220
 4          ZZ      175         200         XZ      240
 5          ZZ      175         200         XZ      248
 6          ZZ      243         200         XZ      220
 7          ZZ      243         200         XZ      240
 8          ZZ      243         200         XZ      248
 9          ZZ      251         300       <NA>       NA
 10         ZZ      309         300       <NA>       NA
 11         ZZ      351         400         XZ      413
 12         ZZ      351         400         XZ      439
 13         ZZ      385         400         XZ      413
 14         ZZ      385         400         XZ      439
 15         ZZ      393         400         XZ      413
 16         ZZ      393         400         XZ      439
 17         ZZ      646         600         XZ      602
 18         ZZ      646         600         XZ      625
 19         ZZ      693         700         XZ      706
 20         ZZ      706         700         XZ      706
 21         ZZ      718         700         XZ      706
 22         ZZ      854         900       <NA>       NA
```

The ideal result I would like to get would be that both 'Price.ZZ' and 'Price.XZ' column would be arranged in ascendant order. NB: I tried to use arrange or order functions to do it, but it does not work on both columns, only one by one.

Here is the code I used and the file is just a random one created with Excel with two columns, a company name and some prices.

```
 library(plyr)
 library(dplyr)
 library(data.table)
 table <- read.table( file.choose(), sep=";", header = TRUE)

 data_ZZ <- subset(table, table$Company == "ZZ")
 data_ZZ$Price_round <- round_any(data_ZZ$Price, 100)
 data_ZZ <- setDT(data_ZZ)[order(Price_round, Price)]
 colnames(data_ZZ) <- c("Company.ZZ", "Price.ZZ", "Price_round")
 data_YZ <- subset(table, table$Company == "YZ")
 data_YZ$Price_round <- round_any(data_YZ$Price, 100)
 data_YZ <- setDT(data_YZ)[order(Price_round, Price)]
 colnames(data_YZ) <- c("Company.YZ", "Price.YZ", "Price_round")
 data_XZ <- subset(table, table$Company == "XZ")
 data_XZ$Price_round <- round_any(data_XZ$Price, 100)
 data_XZ <- arrange(data_XZ, Price)
 colnames(data_XZ) <- c("Company.XZ", "Price.XZ", "Price_round")

 left_join(data_ZZ, data_XZ)
```

I am trying to find the solution since two days... I hope I was clear because it is difficult to describe precisely but I will answer every question :).

Thank you very much. 
Gautier

Comment: Hey Gautier, by what column do you `left_join()`? As far as I see that, there is no join column. So why don't you just use `bind_cols(data_ZZ, data_XZ)`? Otherwise, can you please give use the `head(data_ZZ)` and `head(data_XZ)` from the original data.

Answer (score 0):

I answer to Stephan and give more precisions, thank you for your answer btw.

Here is the head of data_ZZ and data_XZ. It is not the original data, but I tried to reproduce it with fake data (I did not reproduce the other conditions, just the price). Normally, there is a data set, with different companies name, price points, and characteristics regarding those price points. I need to see if I match them, that's why I tried to subset it by company, then round the price to the nearest 100 so I get a common price to match on as they don't have always the same price of course. And after that match it by round price, but it gets disordered and I can't compare it.

```
head(Data_XZ)

Company.XZ Price.XZ Price_round ID
1         XZ       82         100  1
2         XZ       93         100  2
3         XZ      138         100  3
4         XZ      240         200  4
5         XZ      290         300  5
6         XZ      348         300  6

head(Data_YZ) same as ZZ

Company.YZ Price.YZ Price_round
 1:         YZ       76         100
 2:         YZ       93         100
 3:         YZ      146         100
 4:         YZ      240         200
 5:         YZ      280         300
 6:         YZ      348         300
```

I know I was not clear at the beginning, I hope my initial goal is clearer.

Thanks a lot. 
Gautier

Comment: You have posted this as an Answer. Please, instead, Edit your question to update it with this information. (There is an "edit" button at the bottom of the question, below the `r` tag.)

Comment: Also, when you edit your question, please show the desired output that corresponds to this small sample of input. This clarification has made your inputs clear, but showing the desired result will help make your goal clear.